# Apache 2.4 addmodule

Tags: php, apache, php-7, apache2.4, php-7.2

When I add this line to Apache, my Apache doesn't start, but when I delete this row on `httpd.conf`, the apache starts, and I don't know why.

> The line code ;

```
 # Add to the end of the LoadModule section
LoadModule php7_module "C:/php/php7apache2_4.dll"

AddModule mod_php7.c # << This Line !!!

# Add this line inside the <IfModule mod_mime.c> conditional brace
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php

# For syntax highlighted .phps files, also add
#AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? You shouldn't need that line for PHP to work with Apache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AddModule` hasn't been the name of a directive since Apache 1.3.  You're likely following some antiquated guide.